# How to do port forwarding over a public network?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I am stuck in one complicated task , 
 i am having following structure,

```
  _____________________________                  
 | [PC1]--(in same net)--[PC2] |----(Over internet or public net)---[PC3:port1]
                                ----(Over internet or public net)---[PC4:port2]
                                ----(Over internet or public net)---[PC5:port3]
                                .
                                .
                                .n
```

So , First thing all PC are Ubuntu machines
Now , i want to do that have to implement port forwarding on PC2 which help me to connect PC3,PC4,PC5 using different port but when i will use only ip without port it should connect to PC2 only,PC1 and PC2 are in same network but PC3,PC4,PC5 are over public network,how can i do that?
Thanks in advance